# Fade-in Fade-out with CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, fadeout

Here's the complete HTML code that i applied to make 2 quotes fadein and fade out simultaneously .. it works in jfiddle but not on my webpage. Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Here's the jfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n4mKw/)

and here's the HTML Code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    .quotes {display: none;}​
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
    <h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>​

    <script>
    (function() {

        var quotes = $(".quotes");
        var quoteIndex = -1;

        function showNextQuote() {
            ++quoteIndex;
            quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
                .fadeIn(2000)
                .delay(2000)
                .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
        }

        showNextQuote();

    })();​
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you ask your question in a more specific way. What have you tried. Where do you think the error is? Can you find a more specific way to ask what is wrong with my program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your head or body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.quotes {display: none;}​
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>​

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the complete code as it is by you ... It still doesn't works. I am using Mac and browser Chrome and safari. Is that an issue?

Comment: Just fixed my answer, try again. :-)

Comment: That worked! Will accept the answer when the timer runs out. Can you please tell me where i was going wrong?

Comment: At first place you haven't included jQuery. After that there was a strange Unicode symbol just after closing the body.